# Kotlin JPA query inner join using two types

Tags: spring, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Kotlin and JPA. I have an inner join query that gets data from two tables(Postgres). The query works fine. However, since I now have two types (the two tables), using either one only returns all the fields from one of the tables. In order to return all fields, I changed the type to List. However, when I do that, my oject that is returned has no fields, only the raw data. How can I change my code so my json response contains both the name of the fields, as well as the data.

Sorry if my question isn't clear, I'm very new to Kotlin.

UPDATED CODE
my repository code

```
package com.sg.xxx.XXXTTT.report.repository
import com.sg.xxx.XXXTTT.report.model.Report
import com.sg.xxx.XXXTTT.report.model.ReportWithBatches
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import java.time.LocalDate


@Repository
interface IReportRepository : JpaRepository<Report, Long> {

    fun findAllByCreationDate(date: LocalDate): List<Report>

    fun findByReportName(name: String): Report?

    fun findByAdlsFullPath(name: String): Report?

    @Query("SELECT new com.sg.xxx.xxxttt.report.model.ReportWithBatches(r.adlsFullPath, r.sentToXXX, r.contentLength, r.creationDate, r.remoteFileNameOnFTA, b.dataPath , b.version, b.source, r.numberOfRecords) FROM Report r INNER JOIN BatchInfo b ON r.reportUuid = b.reportUuid WHERE r.creationDate = ?1")
    fun findAllByCreationDateJoinBatches(date: LocalDate): List<ReportWithBatches>
}
```

my controller code

```
    @GetMapping(value = ["/linkBatches/{today}"])
    fun findAllByCreationDateJoinBatches(@PathVariable("today") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyyMMdd") date: LocalDate): List<ReportWithBatches> {
        return eligibleService.findAllByCreationDateJoinBatches(date)
    }
```

my DTO

```
package com.sg.xxx.xxxttt.report.model
import java.time.LocalDate

open class ReportWithBatches(
        var adlsFullPath: String?,
        var sentToXXX: Boolean?,
        var contentLength: Long?,
        var creationDate: LocalDate,
        var remoteFileNameOnFTA: String?,
        var dataPath: String?,
        var version: Int?,
        var source: String?,
        var numberOfRecords: Long?
)
```

my function in the service

```
fun findAllByCreationDateJoinBatches(date: LocalDate): List<ReportWithBatches> {
        return reportRepository.findAllByCreationDateJoinBatches(date)
    }
        }
```

Comment: Don't use native queries. Learn JPQL. Here's the documentation about joins in JPQL: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join. Also, between the controller returning JSON, and the query returning data, you can, and should write code that transforms the data into the objects you want, so that you send back the JSON you want. Yoru query actually returns a List<Array<Any?>>, and you can transform this list into whatever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was correctly stated in the comments, the return type of your query is `List<Array<Any?>>`, not `List<Any>`.

Create a data class that would serve as your DTO and map results to it:

```
data class ReportWithBatchInfo(val azureFileName : String, /* more field here */)

fun findAllByCreationDateJoinBatches(date: LocalDate): List<ReportWithBatchInfo> {
    return reportRepository.findAllByCreationDateJoinBatches(date).map {
        ReportWithBatchInfo(it[0] as String, /* more mappings here */)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the direction Alexey. So I updated my code, but I now get an error:  No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [catpipe.report.model.ReportWithBatches]] with root cause. How do I change the query to avoid this error?

Comment: What's the return type of your repository now? It seems by the error that JPA is trying to convert directly to your class, which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I'm not sure what the return type is, I will try to debug .

Comment: Your repository should return `List<Array<Any?>>`, not `List<ReportWithBatches>`. `List<ReportWithBatches>` is returned only from the service, after you map it manually.

Comment: got it! I just have an error with the localDate casting, will figure it out. Thank you! you are very kind.

Comment: I was asked to redo the DTO by storing the data directly into it. This is the example I' trying to follow: https://smarterco.de/spring-data-jpa-query-result-to-dto/. However, since mine is an inner join query, I'm not sure how to make it work. Should I leave ReportsWithBatches as a Data Class? is it correct the way it's done? where are my errors?

Comment: You certainly can use a regular `class` instead of `data class`. Those are questions you should address to one asking for the refactoring.